# Locale fallback from country to language without having to define each individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, fallback, globalize3, rails-i18n

I am localizing an app with the default rails I18n with globalize3 as the back-end.

Is it possible to set a locale with a country code (ie `:fr-CA`) to fallback to its specific language (`:fr`) before going to the default fallback automatically? I know its possible to set each locale/country manually with

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'fr-CA' => 'fr'}
```

But it would be nice to not have to add each fallback manually and have this behaviour automatic.

Comment: In any modern Rails (let's say 6) the country specific locales always fallback to general language locales if fallbacks are enabled. Nothing to do manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve precisely this I have an initializer with

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

See [the source code](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb) for more info.

**Edit:**

This reminds me, there is [an annoying bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/840) in the ActionView LookupContext which prevents this from working for localized views (though it works correcly for locale files). I see it still hasn't been fixed. Basically, if you have any localized views (help pages for example, which are unsuitable to store in locale files due to their length) then a fr-CA locale will **not** fall back to a view called help.fr.html.erb. You either have to name the file help.fr-CA.html.erb **or**, which is what I have done, monkeypatch the LookupContext with another initializer, sort of like this:

```
module ActionView
  class LookupContext
    # Override locale= to also set the I18n.locale. If the current I18n.config object responds
    # to original_config, it means that it's has a copy of the original I18n configuration and it's
    # acting as proxy, which we need to skip.
    def locale=(value)
      if value
        config = I18n.config.respond_to?(:original_config) ? I18n.config.original_config : I18n.config
        config.locale = value[0,2] # only use first part of the locale in lookups
      end
      super(@skip_default_locale ? I18n.locale : default_locale)
    end
  end
end
```

**Another edit:** Note that the patch is rather crude and breaks full locale lookups, going straight for just the language. If you need to also have fully matching views (language-REGION) you'll need to improve my code!

Comment: Thanks. I do not have localized views so the initializer was all I needed.